# access SharedPreferences in a module

Tags: android, module, sharedpreferences

I'm writing an app for driving a robot via Wi-Fi. I have a separate library module with custom preferences to use in my Settings, for example a number picker preference.

I want to develop a "ResetToDefault" Preference. But I want to have opportunity to choose which values I want to reset. I extended DialogPreference and put some checkboxes in the dialog.

I wanted to make it in this function

```
   protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult){
        if(positiveResult){
            if (Box1.isChecked()) {
               //make reset of the preference, which name is diplayed near checkbox
            }
```

Is it possible?
How to access SharedPreferences for the whole app, not only for that module?

It would be easier when I'd put this preference in the app module, but is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

provide the context(Application, Activity,..) then you can access the SharedPreferences in any your own classes

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

more examples in: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java